# Power a diode with a photo diode and an op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode

Can someone please helmp me constuct a circuit that powers a diode by pointing light to the photo diode? I have to use an op amp. I was thinking about negative feedback with a resistor around 100 k ohm to 1 M ohm.

Im doing a project on op amp and the LED should glow while pointing light to the photo diode and then turn off while not pointing any light at it. I know this is a bit nonsense in that way.

Ok, so the power source I can choose between is a 9V battery (which I think doesn't work) and this Power supply:[image: power supply]

The LED is colored. The schematic I tried is this:[image: Schematic]

I tried using negative feedback. Would using the op amp as a comparator be better? Also, while I pointed light at the photo diode at first I got 6 μA. Guessing that the LED needs about 0.65V to be powered I think I should use the 100 kΩ resistor. (Later I actually got it up to 75 μA)

Comment: You are going to have to be a lot more specific about what you are trying to do in order to get a good answer.  Are you trying to actually power an LED with light or just switch the LED on and off with light using an external power source like a battery?

Comment: What do you mean by "power a diode"?

Comment: The Diode should be on while pointing light to the photodiode, and off while not pointing any light at it.

Comment: What power supplies are available?  Why do you have to use an op-amp? How and why did you choose a 100K-1M resistor, and where are you thinking of using it? Do you have a photodiode in mind? Data sheet link?  Which LED will you use? Color? Data sheet?  What have you tried so far, post a schematic of your effort.  This is not a design service where we design circuits for you based on a vaguely worded requirement.

Comment: @Danny 1) You must say LED (light-emitting diode) if that is what you mean. Powering a diode is a bit nonsensical if that is not what you mean. 2) Are you intending to [use the op-amp as a comparator](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html)?

Comment: Ok, these solutions were too complicated. I thought I could do this in an easier way, something like my first schematic. It should be an op amp in the schematic. I have to use the power supply and it should be a voltage to voltage amp or current to voltage amp to amplify the current/voltage from the photo diode. Then the amplified voltage should make the LED glow.

Comment: LED Specs are DO NOT exceed -5V (reverse) !!! and +30mA (forward) You will be violating both specs unless really low current drive OA –

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN7k7H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Add 10uF cap to R7 fixed R or pot to filter AC CEILING LIGHT signals or as req'd.

This bias is for a single supply. Adjust R1 for 20mA if using 9V , and use a shroud (Heat shrink )for light around detector to block stray light including rear ( if transparent)

Answer (score 0):

You might find this approach useful as an alternative:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffKHRj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A voltage of 1V/uA appears accross RV1. You can adjust the sensitivity from 1V/uA down to 0 by adjusting the divider. The op-amp puts a current of 10mA/V through the LED D3.

This turns the LED on brighter depending on the amount of light falling on D2 (operated in photovoltaic mode). R2 limits the current through the LED.

Comment: This would generate -ve input on Vin(+) with light source